# When is $F(A)$ an abelian group?

Tags: abelian-groups

Let $A$ be a nonempty ﬁnite set. Denote by $F(A)$ the set of all bijections  $f : A \to A$.  When is $F(A)$ an abelian group?

Comment: What do you think about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bijection

$f: A \longleftrightarrow A  \tag 1$

is essentially a permutation of the elements of $A$; thus it may be construed as a member of $S_{\vert A \vert }$, the symmetric group acting on $\vert A \vert$ letters.  This group is not abelian for $\vert A \vert \ge 3$, so the bijections don't form an abelian group unless $\vert A \vert \le 2$.

For $\vert A \vert = 1$, $F(A)$ only contains the identity mapping; when $\vert A \vert = 2$, we have the identity and the map which swaps the two elements of $A$; indeed, when $\vert A \vert = 2$, $F(A)$ is $\Bbb Z_2$, the unique two-element group;  it is easy to see these commute.  So for $\vert A \vert \le 2$, $F(A)$ is abelian.

Comment: Thanks, but what does "|A| letters" mean?

Comment: @Peter: The cardinality of $A$; when $A$ is a finite set, it is the number of element in $A$.

Comment: @Peter:  to refine Arturo Magidin's comment one should properly say that the phrase :$\vert A \vert$ letters" refers to the the $\vert A \vert$ *elements* of a set on which $S_A$ acts; they are often represented by $\vert A \vert$ symbols $s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_{\vert A \vert}$ which are called the "letters", since the form a sort of "alphabet", though perhaps for no language other than a mathematical one!.

Comment: Thanks, your explanation is very clear!

Comment: @Peter: my pleasure, sir, and thanks for the "acceptance"!  Cheers!